# group results by id

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do I combine rows by id

Input

```
id  lastOrder               prevOrder
111 2021-09-01T00:00:00Z    (null)
222 2021-06-01T00:00:00Z    (null)
222 (null)                  2021-05-01T00:00:00Z
333 2021-03-01T00:00:00Z    (null)
333 (null)                  2021-02-01T00:00:00Z
```

Desired output

```
id  lastOrder                prevOrder
111 2021-09-01T00:00:00Z    (null)
222 2021-06-01T00:00:00Z    2021-05-01T00:00:00Z
333 2021-03-01T00:00:00Z    2021-02-01T00:00:00Z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation:

```
select id, max(lastOrder), max(prevOrder)
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: there are only 2 rows per id, isn't using "max" a redundancy ?

Comment: @yoodba SQL (ansi, tsql, oracle, mysql) require that a value in the select statement is *either* aggregated (max, min, etc) *or* part of the group by.  Since adding a column to the group by would change the number of records returned, the only option is using an aggregate on the column.

Comment: @yoodba . . . If you have two rows per id, and you want one row combining data from both rows, then `max()` is not redundant.